# Encountered Java.lang.StackOverflowError: null while executing the following code

Tags: java, recursion

```java
class Generate // to print all numbers from 1000 to 9999 whose digits are in ascending order
{
    private boolean order(int n, int i) // checks if the digits of given number are in ascending order
    {
        if (n == 0) return true;
        if (n % 10 < i) return (order(n / 10, n % 10));
        return false;
    }
    void show(int n) // recursive function to generate numbers from 1000 to 9999
    {
        if (n > 9999) // base case for recursor
            System.out.print("");
        else
        {
            if (order(n, 10)) // if digits are in ascending order, prints the number
                System.out.println(n);
            show(n + 1); // recursive call
        }
    }
}
```

The above code was supposed to print all numbers from 1000 to 9999. Code compiled and run but received a runtime exception: `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null`. Would a try-catch block fix my problem? This is my first time posting here hence I am not familiar with the question etiquette, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, catching the error won't fix your code.

Comment: Forgot to tell, I'm using bluej and this is a code for my ISC class 12 practical file

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you show us your `main` method?

Answer (score 0):

Java (and most of the programming languages) provides finite number of memory slot to be used for stack-frame, when your program/code reaches that limit it throws the *StackOverFlow* error.

In your case, your program reaches that limit before coming to base condition.

My take on this -

1. Do not use Recursive approach until and unless you are splitting your problem into acceptable *sub-problems*.
2. [this](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ars213/increasing-the-jvm-memory-allocation-and-thread-stack-size-1027566104.html) shows you how you can increase stack-frame-size to be used by the JVM for a particular thread.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion StackOverFlow is due to double recursion i.e both show(), and order() are recursive... I think show() does not need to be recursive. modified your code as under:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        /
        new Generate().show(); // added main function to get output or exception.. you can omit it and call Generate().show() at the point u require.
    }
}
    class  Generate//to print all numbers from 1000 to 9999 whose digits are in ascending order
{
    private boolean order(int n, int i)//checks if the digits of given number are in ascending order
    {
        if(n==0)
        return true;
        if(n%10<i)
        return(order(n/10,n%10));
        return false;
    }
    void show()//function to generate numbers from 1000 to 9999 - WITHOUT Recursion
    {
        int n = 1000;
        while(n<=9999)
        { if(order(n,10))//if digits are in ascending order, prints the number
            System.out.println(n);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is output: (showing first 7 iterations only)
1234
1235
1236
1237
1238
1239
1245 .......